# Execute onevent with values changed by listener

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I have this code

```
<h:commandLink>
    <f:ajax execute="@this"
            render=":organizerTable :organizerData :delete @form" 
            onevent="deleteOrganizer"
            listener="#{organizercontroller.deletePossible}"/>

    <span id="minus" class="add-on glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>  
</h:commandLink>
```

When I click on the minus, the listener of the ajax tag should be executed before the `onevent`. Normally, it's the other way round.

I tried this:

```
function deleteOrganizer(data) {
    var status = data.status;
    if (status === 'complete') {
        if (#{organizercontroller.canDelete}) {
             alert("Value: " + #{organizercontroller.canDelete});
             window.location.href = "#id_delete_popup";
            }
        else {
            alert("false");
        }
    }
 }
```

Now, the listener method will be executed before my JavaScript function but in `#{organizercontroller.deletePossible}`, I change the value of `canDelete` and this value isn't correct when I read it.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

Using `status === 'success'` didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot seem to find a link/post of adding callback parameters in an ajax call without using PrimeFaces or [OmniFaces Ajax](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax)

But you can always do something like updating a part of the page that contains a javascript function which you update in the ajax call and contains/returns the EL

```
<h:commandLink>
    <f:ajax execute="@this"
            render=":organizerTable :organizerData :delete @form myCallback" 
            onevent="deleteOrganizer"
            listener="#{organizercontroller.deletePossible}"/>

    <span id="minus" class="add-on glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>  
</h:commandLink>
<ui:fragment id="myCallback">
    function myFunction() {
        return #{organizercontroller.deletePossible}
    }
</ui:fragment>
```

and call that function in your ajax response handler

```
function deleteOrganizer(data) {
    var status = data.status;
    if (status === 'complete') {
        if (myFunction()) {
             alert("Value: " + myFunction());
             window.location.href = "#id_delete_popup";
            }
        else {
            alert("false");
        }
    }
}
```